# Python Sockets, data and dictionaries

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, dictionary

So I'm trying to search my dictionary match my data received from the client, however it can never find it.

Here is my server side code:

```
import socket

irTable = {"a1" : "lamp", "a2" : "tv", "b1" : "lamp2", "b2" : "tv2"}

HOST = socket.gethostname()
PORT = 12345
BUFFER = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print('Connection address:', addr)
while 1:
        data = str(conn.recv(BUFFER).decode())
        if not data: break
        print("received data:", data)

for i in irTable:
        if data in irTable:
                print("Found it!")
        else:
                print("Hmm... not there!")

conn.close()
```

And client side:

```
import socket

IP = socket.gethostname()
PORT = 12345
BUFFER = 1024

MSG = "a1"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((IP, PORT))
s.send(MSG.encode())

s.close()
```

So the cliet at the moment only send 'a1' as the data to the server, therefore

```
if data in irTable:
```

should mean

```
if "a1" in irTable:
```

But it never finds a1 in the table even know it's there... All I get is:

```
>>>
Connection address: ('192.168.0.2', 58271)
received data: a1
Hmm... not there!
Hmm... not there!
Hmm... not there!
Hmm... not there!
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add a `print irTable` call and give its output?

Comment: I'm a fairly amateur coder, what do you mean? Sorry

Comment: right before `for i in irTable:`, could you add `print(irTable)`.  I wanted to see that it was what I expected.  But disregard this - Tipu has the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was you are overwriting data after you find it by not breaking out of the loop. so data gets assigned to `a1`, loops again and is assigned to nothing. the following server code works as you expect.

```
import socket

irTable = {"a1" : "lamp", "a2" : "tv", "b1" : "lamp2", "b2" : "tv2"}

HOST = socket.gethostname()
PORT = 12345
BUFFER = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print('Connection address:', addr)
data = None
while not data:
    data = str(conn.recv(BUFFER).decode())

for i in irTable:
        if data in irTable:
                print("Found it!")
        else:
                print("Hmm... not there!")

conn.close()
```

another way using while 1 could be:

```
while 1:
    data = str(conn.recv(BUFFER).decode())
    if data:
        break
```

Comment: Awesome, cheers. One last question, when I run the code and it gives the response on whether its found the dictionary item, it kicks out the print multiple times, in fact for each key. >>> 
('Connection address:', ('192.168.0.11', 52196))
Found it!
Found it!
Found it!
Found it!

Comment: you are searching for the `a1` in the `irTable` the number of times that is the size of `1rTable`. check `if data in irTable` outside of the for loop and eliminate the for loop altogether.